# Configuring network to set wlan0 as primary

Tags: wireless, networking

I recently had to rebuild my pc and decided to go for ubuntu 14.04. I think the mistake I made was I started from a 12.04 install disk instead of the 12.10 disk I'd used previously and when given the option set my primary connection as ethernet (because the wireless option didn't work).

After upgrading to 14.04 etc, I managed to get the wireless working, or more using steps like ifconfig -a and the likes I managed to prove that the wireless card etc. is all installed and working.

However every time I boot without a hard wired connection plugged in I get the message "waiting for network configuration".

I can then once it's booted without a network get my wirless working using

> sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
>   iwlist wlan0 scan

This seems to kick the wireless module into life and it appears in the GUI and I can then select a network, however all the options like edit network and disconnect etc are all greyed out.

What I would like of course is if the WLAN0 was just set as my primary default network so I've been looking for a solution to this and it would seem that I need to adjust the old /etc/network/interfaces file but when I try to do so using the

> sudo vi /etc/network/interfaces

command I, well I simply have no idea what I'm doing. Other than that typing :q! gets me out of there before I do to much damage!

As far as I can tell (by navigating to the file in the GUI) the output of my /etc/network/interfaces is as follows:
(obviously not including the " in each line that's just to break the heading rule of the #)

> "# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
>   "# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).
>
> "# The loopback network interface
>   auto lo
>   iface lo inet loopback
>
> "# The primary network interface
>   auto eth0
>   iface eth0 inet dhcp

If this is the case then this clearly doesn't contain what it should do but I don't how to fix it. Nor do I even know if I'm on the right track.

Any help would be appreciated thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Open your terminal and type as

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

Assume that your Ethernet interface ID is `eth0` .

Then ad this line to that file

`iface eth0 inet manual`

Then restart your Network-Manager with

`sudo service network-manager restart` or restart your PC and check.

Hope that helps.

Comment: This seemed to work, as in when I did the network-manager restart the wireless didn't completely disappear as it had previously but upon restarting the pc it still booted up with the "waiting on network configuration" and I had to go through the process of manually booting the wireless again. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

What I do is remove the default and make a new default.  Windows is much harder to manage, and both use metrics (by increasing the cost to "your" least likely choice) to handle "routing conflicts" when the same destination can be from either device.  The smaller the number/cost of the connection will win -- but if you have two interface routes it can be quite bad if your tunnel dies and then your traffic becomes public again.

1. you can simply type `route` to see your current routing table
2. `route del default eth0`
3. `route add default wlan0`

I usually do this when I create tunnels, so I am usually deleting `wlan0` and adding `ppp0`.  If I leave it alone, I still have the same ISP IP address; So, I need to change my default to the tunnel.